# When a column was created in Postgres table

Tags: postgresql

How to find the date/time when a column has been created on a table? This is a PostgreSQL database.

Thanks

Comment: No, that's not possible.

Comment: You can use event triggers to log changes in the schema. For details look at [Chapter 37. Event Triggers](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/event-triggers.html), [CREATE EVENT TRIGGER](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-createeventtrigger.html), [9.28. Event Trigger Functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-event-triggers.html) and so on.

Comment: Is there any update on this issue?